# Ubuntu OS:: Strongswan Port 500 is not working

Tags: networking, server

I have installed strongswan through "apt-get install strongswan" and all the dependent libraries.

```
root@arjun:~# ipsec up 10.61.186.136
root@arjun:~# ipsec restart
Stopping strongSwan IPsec...
Starting strongSwan 5.9.11 IPsec [starter]...
root@arjun:~#
```

When I do netstat command for charon, I get the following ::

```
root@arjun:~# netstat -alnp | grep charon
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     13056902 1073299/charon       /var/run/charon.enfy
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     13056904 1073299/charon       /var/run/charon.lkp
root@arjun:~#
```

But, when i run the netstat command for the Port 500 required for IPSEC, it is blank::

```
root@arjun:~# netstat -alnp | grep 500
root@arjun:~#
```

Why does the Port 500 corresponding to the IPSEC is blank, doesn't return. What am I missing here ?
Request for suggestions.

Thanks,
Arjun

Comment: `strongwan` requires post-installation configuration. Read `man strongswan`.